# Extract metadata with R

Tags: r

Good day

I am a newbie to Stackoverflow:)
I am trying my hand with programming with R and found this platform a great source of help.

I have developed some code leveraging stackoverflow, but now I am failing to read the metadata from this [htm file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcp0i6cwcmnp91s/facts.htm?dl=0)

Please direct download this file before using in R

```
setwd("~/NLP")
library(tm)
library(rvest)
library(tm.plugin.factiva)
file <-read_html("facts.htm")
source <- FactivaSource(file)
corpus <- Corpus(source, readerControl = list(language = NA))

# See the contents of the documents
inspect(corpus)

head(corpus)
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 3
```

## See meta-data associated with first article

```
meta(corpus[[3]])

meta(corpus[[3]])
  author       : character(0)
  datetimestamp: 2017-08-31
  description  : character(0)
  heading      : Rain, Rain, Rain
  id           : TIMEUK-170830-e
  language     : en
  origin       : thetimes.co.uk
  edition      : character(0)
  section      : Comment
  subject      : c("Hurricanes/Typhoons", "Storms", "Political/General News", "Disasters/Accidents", "Natural Disasters/Catastrophes", "Risk News", "Weather")
  coverage     : c("United States", "North America")
  company      : character(0)
  industry     : character(0)
  infocode     : character(0)
  infodesc     : character(0)
  wordcount    : 333
  publisher    : News UK & Ireland Limited
  rights       : © Times Newspapers Limited 2017
```

How can I save each metadata (SE, HD, AU, ..PUB, AU) - all 18 metadata elements column-wise in a dataframe or write to excel for each document in corpus?

Example of output:

```
     SE HD AU ...
Doc 1
    2
    3
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Take `head(corpus)` and show us the data. If you would like help sorting the data into your groupings we need to know what it looks like.

Comment: @sconfluentus thank you for your advise - I have added this to the above

Comment: @Sotos - I hope my changes are to your satisfaction

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know of to do it is:

Make a data frame from each of the three lists in your `corpus`:

```
one<-data.frame(unlist(meta(corpus[[1]])))
two<-data.frame(unlist(meta(corpus[[2]])))
three<-data.frame(unlist(meta(corpus[[3]])))
```

Then you will want to merge them into a single data frame. For the first two, this is easy to do, as using `"row.names"` will cause them to merge on the NON VARIABLE row names. But the second merge, you need to merge based on the column now named `"Row.Names"`     So you need to create and rename the first column of the third file with the row names, using `setDT` allows you to do this without adding another full set of information, just redirecting R to see the row names as the first column

```
setDT(three, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
colnames(three)[1] <- "Row.names"
```

then you simply merge the first and second data frame into variable named `meta`, and then merge meta with `three` using "Row.names" (the new name of the first column now).

```
meta <- merge(one, two, by="row.names", all=TRUE) 
meta <- merge(meta, three, by = "Row.names", all=TRUE)
```

Your data will look like this:

```
  Row.names unlist.meta.corpus..1.... unlist.meta.corpus..2.... unlist.meta.corpus..3....
1    author             Jenni Russell                      <NA>                      <NA>
2 coverage1             United States               North Korea             United States
3 coverage2             North America             United States             North America
4 coverage3                      <NA>                     Japan                      <NA>
5 coverage4                      <NA>                 Pyongyang                      <NA>
6 coverage5                      <NA>              Asia Pacific                      <NA>
```

Those `NA` values are there because not all of the sub-lists had values for all of the observations.

By using the `all=TRUE` on both merges, you preserve all of the fields, with and without data, which makes it easy to work with moving forward.

If you look at this [PDF from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.factiva/tm.plugin.factiva.pdf) on page two the section *Details* shows you how to access the content and metadata. From there is is simply about *unlisting* to move them into data frames.

If you get lost, send a comment and I will do what I can to help you out!

**EDIT BY REQUEST:**

To write this to Excel is not super difficult because the data is already "square" in a uniform data frame. You would just install `xlsx` package and `xlxsjars` then use the following function:

```
write.xlsx(meta, file, sheetName="Sheet1",
col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, showNA=TRUE)
```

You can find information [about the package here:](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) page 38 gives more detail.
 And if you want to save the content, you can change `meta` to `content` in the files which extract the data from corpus and make the initial dataframes. The entire process will be the same otherwise

Comment: Thank @sconfluentus - this is perfect. How can I also save the content of the articles as well in the excel file. Metadata in htm is listed as TD.

Comment: Thank you @sconfluentus - your note to change to 'meta' to 'content' is very useful